# fwrite to create new pages

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm very new to php and so far in everything I have wanted to do I have been able to search the web for a solution. And after hours of reading what I could find and still not being able to figure it out I come to you..

Here is what I'm doing I'm creating a form where someone can upload some information and then that information populates in to an inventory page as long as well as there own page, and create a more in depth full page for each submission based on a template. All form information is stored in a mysql database.

I have gotten all if to work except the last piece. I'm trying to use fwrite to do this. I'll post what I have for that section. I do know that I'm missing some major steps here. Any guidance or a point in the right direction would be nice.

Thanks!

```
<?php

// For use in creating individual page
$tpl_file = "properties.php"; // template
$tpl_path = "pages/"; // where template is stored
$submissions_path = "new-pages/"; // where new file will be stored



$fp = fopen($submissions_path, "w");
fwrite($fp, $tpl_file);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Never allow user input to write to a php file!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're opening a directory using a file operation, which will not work. fopen() works on FILES, not directories.

Most likely what you're after is

```
$path = $submissions_path . $tpl_path . $tpl_file;
$fp = fopen($path, 'w') or die("Failed open $path for writing");
```

Note the added `or die()` business - it is always a good idea to verify that a file system operation succeeded (or failed) before you proceed. Assuming success will bite you in the rump at some point.

Comment: Thanks! One step closer! I had to take out the $submissions_path out of $path. That took all the bugs out however I cant get the new page to create still.. Any thought?